# Why use async.gather in Python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Let's say we have

```
await async_function_one_with_large_IO_request()
await async_function_two_with_large_IO_request()
```

versus

```
asyncio.gather(
  async_function_one_with_large_IO_request(), 
  async_function_two_with_large_IO_request())
```

In the first version, once we hit the 'large io request' part of function one, it's gonna move onto running function_two, that's the whole point of `await`, right?

Isn't that what version 2 with gather does too?

What's the performance difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the first version, once we hit the 'large io request' part of function one, it's gonna move onto running function_two, that's the whole point of await, right?

That's incorrect. In your first version, `async_function_two_with_large_IO_request` (which I will call `function_two`) won't run until `async_function_one_with_large_IO_request` (which I will call `function_one`) *completes*.

If `function_one` happens to `await` on another function, it will yield control to another running async task, but `function_two` hasn't been scheduled yet.

When you use `asyncio.gather`, the tasks are scheduled concurrently, so if `function_one` `await`s on something, `function_two` has a chance to run (along with other async tasks).

---

Note that `asyncio.gather` creates an async task, which generally implies you have to `await` on it:

```
await asyncio.gather(...)
```

The Python documentation covers this in detail in [Coroutines and Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html).

Comment: so what does 'await' really do under the hood?

Comment: It causes the calling async task to yield control to the async scheduler, which may schedule another async task. When the `await`-ed function completes, the calling tasks is eligible to be scheduled again the next time another tasks calls `await`.

Comment: https://realpython.com/async-io-python is a good overview of asyncio programming in Python.

Comment: one more question. in that example, does asyncio.gather create its own mini-event loop that only includes the two functions? ie, async.gather will block until both functions passed in are finished?

Comment: `asyncio.gather` creates an async task. You need to `await` on the result. It is scheduled like any other async task.